# Checking two values from two tables for duplicates

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I have an existing check that looks at the Name table to check for duplicate names (Full_Name), but how can I check for Name and Address ? Full_Address lives in the address table and when I try to combine these two values to check against the DB as a single value everything breaks.

```
Select Name.ID, Name.Full_Name, Concat(Name.Full_Name,' ', Address.FULL_ADDRESS) as Comb 
FROM Name INNER JOIN Address ON Name.ID = Address.ID
Where Full_Name != '' AND having count(Comb)>1
group by Full_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Name TABLE (ID INT, Full_Name NVARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Address TABLE (ID INT, FULL_ADDRESS NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Name VALUES
     (1,'Alex Zoolittle')
    ,(2,'Brian Yakami')
    ,(3,'Charles Xylogon')
    ,(4,'Brian Yakami')

INSERT INTO @Address VALUES
     (1,'123 Westwood Way, Los Angeles, CA 95043')
    ,(2,'234 Eastwood Lane, Los Gatos, CA 95030')
    ,(3,'345 Northwood Blvd, Los Alamos, NM 83241')
    ,(4,'234 Eastwood Lane, Los Gatos, CA 95030')

;WITH Comb
    AS (
        SELECT na.ID, na.Full_Name, CONCAT(na.Full_Name,' ', ad.FULL_ADDRESS) AS Comb,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(na.Full_Name,' ', ad.FULL_ADDRESS) ORDER BY na.ID) AS Row
            FROM @Name na
                INNER JOIN @Address ad
                    ON na.ID = ad.ID
        WHERE Full_Name != ''
        )

SELECT ID, Full_Name, Comb FROM Comb
    WHERE Row = 1
```